# numpy ndarrays: row-wise and column-wise operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I wanted to apply a function row-wise (or column-wise) to an ndarray, do I look to ufuncs (doesn't seem like it) or some type of array broadcasting (not what I'm looking for either?) ?

**Edit**

I am looking for something like R's apply function. For instance,

```
apply(X,1,function(x) x*2)
```

would multiply 2 to each row of X through an anonymously defined function, but could also be a named function. (This is of course a silly, contrived example in which `apply` is not actually needed). There is no generic way to apply a function across an NumPy array's "axis", ?

Comment: It's easier to talk about specifics. What are you wanting to do?  A generic "apply this function row-wise" solution is effectively just a for loop (it's really easy to iterate over rows or columns).  There's usually a more efficient way.

Comment: The equivalent of R's `apply` is `numpy.vectorize` for what it's worth. It's almost always a bad idea to use it, though... I've never seen a case where you could use `vectorize` where you can't rewrite the function to just operate on ND arrays directly.  (It's quite possibly less flexible than R's `apply`. I've only played with `R`, never really used it in depth.) In the case of your example, you'd just write `result = X * 2`.

Comment: Interesting -- actually R has a vectorize function as well -- but to apply it along an "axis" I would have to split the array into lists of row-wise vectors or something... but thanks for the general discussion. I'll probably stick to the looping as it seems more "universal". (in R you can also just do `X*2` in this case, which is why I said it was silly :).

Comment: Ah! Sorry I just assumed that R's `apply` was a bit different. You can make numpy's `vectorize` operate on rows (you view the array as a structured array, and then each element is a vector), but it's more trouble than it's worth (and generally not any faster than a for loop over the rows).

Comment: "and then each element is a vector" is meant to be, each row is a tuple? It would shorten the code, but less general as it's only applicable row-wise... but interesting idea!

Comment: Actually, I completely forgot about `numpy.apply_along_axis`. It's probably much closer to what you're looking for...

Comment: Ah. Well... that is exactly it! But so wouldn't it make more sense to use that instead of your decorator below? Of there is an advantage to the decorator approach (apart from the syntax of just being able to call "test" on a 2-d array)?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same as the decorator below, actually. The decorator has no advantages. I just forgot about `apply_along_axis`.  `apply_along_axis` is slightly more complex, but it's still just a python for loop over the axis in question.

Comment: But `apply_along_axis` loops in C though rather than in Python? Or that's what R's `apply` does I think. In any case, I am growing so strong with knowledge -- thanks for your feedback.

Comment: No, actually `apply_along_axis` loops in python. Have a look at the source: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/shape_base.py  Either way, a lot of the overhead is in calling a python function, so moving the loops to C wouldn't make a large difference. (It would probably be a bit faster.) Calling a python function, even if you call it from C, is rather expensive.

Comment: Ah, that's where it's defined... great, thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First off, many numpy functions take an `axis` argument. It's probably possible (and better) to do what you want with that sort of approach.

However, a generic "apply this function row-wise" approach would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def rowwise(func):
    def new_func(array2d, **kwargs):
        # Run the function once to determine the size of the output
        val = func(array2d[0], **kwargs)
        output_array = np.zeros((array2d.shape[0], val.size), dtype=val.dtype)
        output_array[0] = val
        for i,row in enumerate(array2d[1:], start=1):
            output_array[i] = func(row, **kwargs)
        return output_array
    return new_func

@rowwise
def test(data):
    return np.cumsum(data)

x = np.arange(20).reshape((4,5))
print test(x)
```

Keep in mind that we can do exactly the same thing with just:

```
np.cumsum(x, axis=1)
```

There's often a better way that the generic approach, especially with numpy.

Edit:

I completely forgot about it, but the above is essentially equivalent to `numpy.apply_along_axis`.

So, we could re-write that as:

```
import numpy as np

def test(row):
    return np.cumsum(row)

x = np.arange(20).reshape((4,5))
print np.apply_along_axis(test, 1, x)
```

Comment: Wow, very elegant!... but basically the way to do it for a user-defined function not defined by numpy with an axis argument is to  iterate over rows and assigning to a pre-allocated array...

Comment: Yes. There are other ways of doing the same thing, (you can even make `numpy.vectorize` do some crazy things through various tricks) but they all wind up being similar to the example above.  Like I said, though, you can usually cast your user-defined function as a combination of various numpy functions that do take an axis argument.  Sometimes it's a better approach, sometimes it's not.  Iteration (like the above example) will often use much less memory than the "numpy-ified" version, though it's usually slower.